# Find out which UITableView the button belongs to

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

In landscape view I have a UIScrollView where I add UITableViews dynamically. UITableViews are 200px wide so there are can be 2-3 of them on the screen. Each cell has a button.

When the button is pushed how can I know which UITableView that button belong to?

PS implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell = (CellHistory*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if(!cell)
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellHistory" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CellHistory class]])
        {
            cell = (CellHistory *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}


UIButton *noteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[noteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[cell addSubview:noteButton];
[noteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
```

PS2 how I add UITableViews to UIScrollView:

```
for (int i=0; i<allDays.count; i++) {
            CGRect landTableRect = CGRectMake(landContentOffset+0.0f, 60.0f, 200.0f, 307.0f);
            landTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:landTableRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [landTableView setTag:i];
            [landTableView setNeedsDisplay];
            [landTableView setNeedsLayout];
            landTableView.delegate = self;
            landTableView.dataSource = self;
            [_landScrollView addSubview:landTableView];
            [landTableView reloadData];
            landContentOffset += landTableView.frame.size.width;
            _landScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(landContentOffset, _landScrollView.frame.size.height);
            [allLandTableViews addObject:landTableView];
        }
```

Comment: How have you added the button in the cell? `[cell.contentView addSubview:]` or `[cell addSubview:]` ?

Show the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a tag to each button that matches the tag for each table view. Then you can compare them

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check

```
if (tableView == youTableViewA)
    button.tag = 1;
else if (tableView == yourTableViewB)
    button.tag = 2;
```

.
.
.
And so on.

Where you are assigning a target to your button with `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` make sure your target method accepts a parameter:

```
- (void) targetMethod:(id)sender{

    if (sender.tag == 1){

        //tableViewA

    }else if (sender.tag == 2){

        //tableViewB

    }

}
```

.
.
.
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helpful category method on `UIView` to just walk your view hierarchy until a matching parent is discovered:

```
@implementation UIView (ParentOfClass)

- (UIView *)parentViewWithClass:(Class)aClass
{
    UIView *current = self;
    UIView *result = nil;
    while ((current = current.superview) != nil) {
        if ([current isKindOfClass:aClass]) {
            result = current;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@end
```

Then in your `UIButton` handling code you get the UITableView by a simple call:

```
- (IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender
{
    UITableView *tableView = [sender parentViewWithClass:[UITableView class]];
    // ...
}
```